# HikariPool active connection stuck and will not be run

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, mybatis, hikaricp

I'm running a simple update query with MyBatis in my SpringBoot project, and using Hiraki connection pool.

In testing stage, only single tread of update query is execute in the program.  When the program reach the line of update query, the Hikari connection start successfully but somehow the active connection will not be run and stuck forever.

```
//my hikari datasource setup
@Bean
public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource db = new HikariDataSource();
    db.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    db.setJdbcUrl(url);
    db.setUsername(username);
    db.setPassword(pwd);
    db.setReadOnly(false);
    db.setMaximunPoolSize(80);
    db.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    db.setIdleTimeout(30000);
    db.setMaxLifetime(30000);
    db.setMinimunIdle(5);
    db.setValidationTimeout(500);
    return db;
}
```

Following is the screenshot of stacktrace
[image]

It's weird, this situation will not occur if i use insert statement, it only happen when I call update statement

Comment: A SQL statement that *starts successfully but somehow has problems to end* may point to *performance problems* - show the statement and the *execution  plan* (in text - not as a screenshot)

Comment: Maybe your SQL is problematic or you have another update which lock the record

Comment: You need to check `dba_lockers`/`dba_waiter` table in the database when this happens. It looks like some other modifying operation blocks the query. Do you have a `SQL*Plus` running with uncommitted transaction?

Comment: Is it resolved? How you are accessing connection object from the pool. Please add a piece of code.